# How to evaluate limiting value of sums of a specific type

Tags: limits, summation

We know that if $f$ is integrable in (0,1) then

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k/n) = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx.
$$

Recently I found the following sum

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n^2 + k^2} = \frac{\ln 2}{2}.
$$

This sum cannot be expressed in the form $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k/n)$. Rather it is of the form

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n} k f(k/n).
$$

**Part 1**

Is there any technique to evaluate limits of this form?

**Part 2**

Generalizing the question one step further, how can we asymptotics of summations of the form

$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}  f(k)g\Big(\frac{k}{n}\Big).
$$

Comment: But if it is of the form $n^{-2}\sum_k k\cdot f(k/n)$, if we let $g(x) = xf(x)$, then $n^{-2}\sum_k k \cdot f(k/n) = n^{-1} \sum_k k/n\cdot f(k/n) = n^{-1} \sum_k g(k/n)$. Just we just have to change the function, don't we?

Comment: Why would you mask a valid answer as a comment?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Didn't think long about it, it just popped to my mind when I was reading the question ... will write an answer now,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's rewrite your sum. Note, that we have 
$$ 
\frac 1{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot f(k/n) = \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n \frac kn \cdot f(k/n) 
$$
So, if we define $g \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ by $g(x) = xf(x)$, we get 
$$ 
\frac 1{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot f(k/n) = \frac 1n \sum_{k=1}^n g(k/n), $$
which for $n \to \infty$ converges, as you noted to 
$$ \int_0^1 g(x) \, dx = \int_0^1 x\cdot f(x)\, dx. $$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have added a second part to the question. Could you please have a look at it?

Comment: @user60930 You should ask that in a different new post.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n^2+k^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\frac{nk}{n^2+k^2}$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\frac{nk}{n^2+k^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\frac{\frac{k}{n}}{1+(\frac{k}{n})^2}$$

so $$f(\frac{k}{n})=\frac{\frac{k}{n}}{1+(\frac{k}{n})^2}$$

so $$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$$

and $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n}\frac{nk}{n^2+k^2}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{nk}{n^2+k^2}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{ln 2}{2}$$