# Another limit of summation

Tags: limits, summation

Please help - how to solve this:

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{1+\frac{k^6}{n^3}}} $$

Comment: Could you tell what you tried ?

Comment: $$\sum_{0\le k\le n-1}k^6=O(n^7)$$

Comment: Are you sure you copied this problem correctly?  there are a couple of oddities in it.  (For example, the $\frac{1}{n^3}$ term can be pulled through the sum.)

Comment: Thank you very much,the formula is rewriten.

Comment: I think it should be 0. But I couldn't prove this.

Comment: You could try linking this limit with an integral sum.

Comment: This should be similar enough:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/400174/how-to-evaluate-limiting-value-of-sums-of-a-specific-type

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following.

Put $$f(k,n)= \frac{1}{1+\frac{k^6}{n^3}}.$$ Then $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} f(k,n)\le \sum_{k\le n^{2/3}}f(k,n) + \sum_{k\ge n^{2/3}} f(k,n)
\le n^{2/3}+\frac{n}{1+n}.$$ Hence $$0\le \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n} f(k,n)\le \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1{n}\left(n^{2/3}+\frac{n}{1+n}\right)=0.$$